# An infinite product problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $\prod(1+a_n)$ converges where $a_n =  1/{\sqrt n} + 1/n$ for n odd, $-1/\sqrt n$ for n even.

I tried to multiplying even number of terms, but it's not cancelled well. All I found is that $(1+a_{2n-1})(1+a_{2n})=\dfrac{2n+\sqrt{2n-1}}{2n+\sqrt{2n}}$. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might note that
$$
(1+a_{2n-1})(1+a_{2n})=1-\frac1{\sqrt{2n}(\sqrt{2n}+1)(\sqrt{2n}+\sqrt{2n-1})}
$$
and try to take it from there.